# New InputController is spawned each time opening windows menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I'm working on a small game project using Windows Mixed Reality headset (Lenovo Explorer) and Unity. I'm currently running the latest MRTK v2.1 release.

I'm using a custom right hand controller. It's a prefab where the main object has the following components:

1. the mrtk's `WindowsMixedRealityControllerVisualizer` script
2. An Input controller script (using `IMixedRealityInputHandler`) to manage  input into Actions (shoot, jump, etc)
3. A custom script dealing with the actual actions in the VR world.

Besides the component, it has a child object which is the 3D model prefab of the object I want rendered. It is in a child so I could place it correctly with some offset. AFAIK this is not a problem. The this whole thing is its own prefab that I then add on my custom `MixedRealityControllerVisualizationProfile`under *Global Right Hand Controller Model*. In general this works just as I want it. The controller is rendered correctly on my right hand and the inputs behave like I wanted them too.

My problem is that once in the game, when I click the **Home** button (windows logo) to show the floating menu, once I click a second time to go back to the game, a **new** controller is spawned at 0,0,0 (or where my hand is at the time of returning to the game); I still have one on my hand though, and this new one it **also** responds to input the same way the one on my hand. If I open/close the home button again this repeats and I end up with several controllers spawned. So when I *shoot*, a shot is fired both from my hand, and from the new controller at 0,0,0 (or from as many controllers I've ended up in the scene with by then)

I don't think my controller is ever loosing tracking so IDK why mrtk is spawning a new one. I've considered to check for extra controller objects in the scene and deleting them manually per every update but that sounds silly, there must be some configuration somewhere that can surely take care of this no? Doesn't the visualizer script takes care of this?

I've look around online but haven't found anything specific about this. Any clues will be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in the MRTK.  I would recommend filing and issue on the github repository at https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues